# Override css rules of a plugin within my own theme

Tags: plugins, themes

I want to override some rules of a plugin css file within my own theme so next time that I updated that plugin, my settings of that plugin be in a safe place . currently I copied that css file into my theme and changed some rules.So then I need to override this rules.
I think found an answer that is related to my question ([HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106116)) but I can't understand this code. how it works?

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'wpse106104_replace_stylesheet', 10, 2 );
function wpse106104_replace_stylesheet( $stylesheet_src, $handle ){
   if( 'plugin-script-handle' == $handle ){
        $stylesheet_src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/themes-copy-of-plugin.css';
   }
return $stylesheet_src;
}
```

Comment: It replaces the src paremeter (url of the css file) with another one. What don't you understand exacly?

Comment: Yes, it's right.
But I'm trouble with how it know which one of the plugins I want to override on it? (apologies for my bad English)

Comment: It checks the plugin's handler, `plugin-script-handle` in this case. The handler is the first parameter of `wp_enqueue_style()` used to enqueue the stylesheet.

Comment: I'm post it as a question so you can mark this topic as resolved and other users can find the answer easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style_loader_src` filter is used to modify/filter the src (url) of a stylesheet. The function callback accepts two parameters, the first is the original src and the second the handler of the stylesheet. The handler is the first parameter of `wp_enqueue_style()` used to enqueue the stylesheet.

So, to replace a stylsheet source with another one you should check the handler to know wchich stylesheet it must replaced, in the code you posted the checked handler is `plugin-script-handle`.